# Не могу понять, когда надо писать "не" слитно, а когда раздельно

Tags: орфография

Не могу понять, когда надо писать "не" слитно, а когда раздельно.

> Люди никогда **не довольны** настоящим.
>
> Мужчины и дамы были по большей части **недовольны** ею.
>
> Герман очень **недоволен** своим приятелем.
>
> Нельзя было понять, был ли доволен или **не доволен** диспозицией.
>
> Император не будет **недоволен** этим излишним усердием.
>
> Вывод состоит в том, что описания эти **не верны.**
>
> Сведения о движении французов были всегда **неверны.**
>
> Мороз показался **не велик.**
>
> Данило был **невелик** ростом.

Answer (score 2):

Люди никогда не довольны настоящим.-отрицательное наречие подчёркивает отрицание.

Мужчины и дамы были по большей части недовольны ею.Можно заменить прилагательное с не синонимом без не: недовольны = сердиты=возмущены

Герман очень недоволен своим приятелем.Можно заменить синонимом возмущён

Нельзя было понять, был ли доволен или не доволен диспозицией.Это антитеза - противопоставление доволен / не доволен в значении удовлетворён / не удовлетворён. Л.Толстой подчёркивает это противопоставление, чтобы показать иронию в изображении поведения генералов по отношению к Вейротеру:
" Но по значению этого значительного взгляда нельзя было понять, был ли он согласен или не согласен, доволен или не доволен диспозицией”.

Император не будет недоволен этим излишним усердием. Недоволен = сердит - можно заменить синонимом.

Вывод состоит в том, что описания эти не верны.-отрицается верность описаний.

Сведения о движении французов были всегда неверны.- утверждается ошибочность сведений, доставляемых Наполеону.

Мороз показался не велик.- отрицается сила мороза.

Данило был невелик ростом.-невелик=мал. Можно заменить синонимом.

Comment: Вот таблицы в помощь:http://5-ege.ru/pravopisanie-ne-i-ni/

Answer (score 1):

А) Люди никогда не довольны настоящим. Мужчины и дамы были по большей части недовольны ею. Герман очень недоволен своим приятелем. Нельзя было понять, был ли доволен или недоволен диспозицией (у Л. Толстого слитное написание). Император не будет недоволен этим излишним усердием.Вывод состоит в том, что описания эти неверны.  Сведения о движении французов были всегда неверны.

Б) Мороз показался не велик. Данило был невелик ростом.

А) Доволен - недоволен (только два состояния, позитивное и негативное), верны - неверны (только две оценки, позитивная и негативная). Раздельное написание (не доволен, не верны) ничего не дает, не меняет смысла, поэтому надо писать слитно (недоволен, неверны). Но: люди никогда не довольны, здесь особая грамматика, отрицательное наречие, слитно писать нельзя.

Б) Велик - не велик - невелик - мал. Здесь при разном написании разный смысл, его выбирает автор: Мороз показался не велик (средний мороз, а ожидался сильный). Данило был невелик (мал) ростом.  Оба варианта возможны, поэтому желательно видеть весь текст.

Answer (score 0):

При раздельном написании "не" отрицается утверждение, а при слитном — утверждается отрицание.

После "никогда", "нигде", "никто" и других слов с "ни-", то есть при усилении отрицания, "не" с кратким прилагательным пишется раздельно.

При двойном отрицании ("не будет недоволен") написать "не доволен" раздельно было бы странно хотя бы потому, что так пришлось бы долго соображать, что имеется в виду.

*Сведения были всегда* каковы? Неверны — лучше слитно. Без "всегда" можно было бы и раздельно написать. *Описания не верны* = не являются верными. В *четвёртом* да, Niemand прав, мне тоже кажется, что лучше слитно. *Были недовольны* либо *не были довольны.* С "по большей части" второй вариант отпадает. С "очень" тоже писать раздельно неестественно, п. ч. напрашивается утверждение, очень какой-то. *Мороз **не был** сильным.* *А Данило был невелик (или низок) ростом.* С глаголами "был", "будет", "стал", "оказался" и др., отражающими состояние, вообще неестественно писать раздельно.

Comment: Послушайте, **с глаголами** "не" **всегда** раздельно. Ну кроме единичных, давным-давно оговоренных случаев. При чем тут глаголы состояния?!

Comment: Я хотел сказать, что после таких глаголов краткое причастие с "не" обычно (а может, и всегда) пишется слитно.